# Flurry Event Values show "com.flurry.OTHER"

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I Integrated Flurry in my iOS App.
I added Some Events.

I am passing "EventName" as "String value" and "EventValue" as "URL String".

But When I checked in flurry analytics For Event_URL sometimes its showing 
  com.flurry.OTHER"
Any idea why its showing com.flurry.OTHER"

```
NSString *eventName = "EVENT NAME"; NSString *eventValue = "https://myname/myimage.gif";
NSMutableDictionary *articleParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [articleParams setObject:eventName forKey:@"Event_Name"];
        [articleParams setObject:eventValue forKey:@"Event_URL"];
        [Flurry logEvent:@"Event_Detail" withParameters:articleParams];
```

Answer (score 1):

An event parameter can have an infinite number of values but the reporting api is only capable of returning the top X values (I believe it is 500) and the remainder are reported as "com.flurry.OTHER".

Using event parameters is a good way to track data that occurs somewhat frequently, and less useful for tracking high numbers of unique values. Flurry can not provide all of the event parameter data when there are thousands of unique values (ie very high cardinality).

Comment: It means if i have put the event on any screen then if user base increases then it will give tracking for first 500 only.

Comment: You will be able to see the top 500 most frequently occurring parameter values across all of your apps's users.