# What does “com.flurry.OTHER” mean

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I added a event with flurry in my application, but it shows “com.flurry.OTHER”. I'm sure that I didn't post such value. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Please refer to the answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559331/flurry-event-values-show-com-flurry-other

Answer (score 2):

This is a label used by Flurry, on event parameters with very high cardinality. For high cardinality parameters, Flurry groups all values beyond a certain number into the same group, and gives that group the label com.flurry.other. The name ensures that it does not conflict with real values that you may record such as "Other." It isn't possible to remove the value.